# Is it's possible make GUI and console app in one exe?

Tags: user-interface, console, console-application, d

I want to develop App with GUI, that can be run without showing GUI. How I can do it?

If it's possible would this App work on servers that do not have nothing related with GUI (ex: can I work with such App with ssh or so).

Any example please if it's possible.

Comment: Windows or Linux example ?

Comment: This certainly is possible, though questionable. Usually the approach is to make one cli application and an additional GUI application that internally uses the logic inside the cli application. That way you have both without making things unnecessary complex. If you still want to give it a try: opening a window is an active task done by an application. If your application chooses not to, then it is a cli application. That decision can be made on a dynamical base: by considering call arguments or by checking if a GUI environment is available at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it isn't always easy though and might not be worth it. The general idea is to write a console program that attempts to dynamically load the gui libraries and create a window. If that succeeds, it detaches from the console/controlling terminal and becomes a gui program. On Windows, this may pop up a console window briefly when the user double clicks the exe as it would be created first, then quickly destroyed.

You would want to dynamically load the gui with dlopen/LoadLibrary because the libs might not even be present on the computer you're running on, and if you rely on the system to load them at startup, your program won't run at all when they are missing. This is the  most painful part - checking the return value of XOpenDisplay or CreateWindow or whatever is easy, and detaching from a console is easy (FreeConsole or fork). But first you need to get your program to actually start in the worst case scenario of no client side gui libraries at all.

If you're ok with ignoring that case - if the libs are present but the display isn't, you just handle it as a regular runtime error - then it isn't too hard at all.

Comment: As Adam said, it is possible, and I neither think it is worth for it or is a wise conception. I would go with two version one with and one without GUI and add some wrapper which deal with it maybe with some `--gui` or `--console` parameters.

Comment: And what about main function? I looked at dlanggui and do not found any main there? Could anybody explain difference between main in console apps and gui libs without main?

Comment: You can use the same main function for both. I don't know how dlanggui does it, they might use a WinMain or a main hidden in the library, but you don't have to do that (and I recommend against it, just use a regular main)